# Room @Relation using a composite index

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

**Context**

Hello, I'm working with 2 tables related by a foreign key, WorkOrderItemUsage and WorkOrderItemUsageLot. Every workOrderItemUsage can have multiple lots, so it's a 1 to n relationship, to make my work easier I'm implementing a helper entity called WorkOrderItemUsageWithLots, it's used to retrieve all the data from both tables in one go using room @Relation.

**Problem**

I've tried to use @Relation with a single column and it works correctly, but I need to stablish my relation based on a composite key like the foreign key, I understand there's no support for composite keys using @Relation I'm trying to link it using an index, Am I missing something? Do I have to refuse to use @Relation in favor of good ol SQL joins in queries?

- error: Cannot find the parent entity column `woItemUsagePk` in WorkOrderItemUsageWithLots
- Error prints the available columns for @Relation
- Options: woIdItemUsage, itemId, itemNumber, itemThirdNumber, itemDescription, quantityMeasure, branchId, branchDescription, locationId, doseQuantity, doseMeasureUnit, itemAction, itemPlague, itemJustification
  private java.util.List lotList

  ```
  @Entity(
  primaryKeys = ["itemId", "branchId", "woIdItemUsage"],
  foreignKeys = [
      ForeignKey(entity = WorkOrder::class,
              parentColumns = ["woId"],
              childColumns = ["woIdItemUsage"],
              onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
              onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE)],
  indices = [Index("woIdItemUsage", "itemId", "branchId", name = "woItemUsagePk", unique = true)]

  @Entity(
          primaryKeys = ["woIdItemUsageLot", "itemId", "branchId", "lotId"],
          foreignKeys = [
              ForeignKey(entity = WorkOrderItemUsage::class,
                      parentColumns = ["woIdItemUsage", "itemId", "branchId"], 
                      childColumns = ["woIdItemUsageLot", "itemId", "branchId"],
                      onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
                      onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE)],
          indices = [Index("woIdItemUsageLot", "itemId", "branchId", name = "woItemUsageLotPk", unique = true)])




  class WorkOrderItemUsageWithLots(@Embedded var itemUsage: WorkOrderItemUsage) {

  @Relation(parentColumn = "woItemUsagePk", entityColumn= "woItemUsageLotPk")
  var lotList: List<WorkOrderItemUsageLot> = emptyList()}
  ```

Comment: I implemented it using an entity with @Embebed fields and inner join on the SQL query

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a `woItemUsagePk` field declared in your entity class. You need to declare a field to hold the value, Room is not going to dynamically declare it for you.

Comment: This was a hack / workaround to try to work using Relation annotation with composite primary key, so i could take advantage of @Relation on queries but thats not supported yet. I decided to go for "using an entity with Embebed fields and inner join on the SQL query".